# what happened behind the scene when override a function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to understand what is happening when I'm executing the following code

```
def func1():
    print("this is function 1")

def func2():
    print("this is function 2")

def turn_into_another_func(func):
    return func

func1 = turn_into_another_func(func2)
func1()
```

Did I override the function func1 with the variable func1?

Or is func1 actually changed into func2.

Can you please refer me to a relevant Python documentation to read more about this. Specifically I would like to understand how to properly use it what are the consequences.
Also, as far as the terminology - is the "override" correct here or should another term be used?
I appreciate any help

Comment: All you did is making `func1` a copy of `func2`.

Comment: as I mentioned before I'm now to python, what does a copy mean?
Is func1 is "pointing" to the address of func2 and if so can I access func1 in some way?

Comment: "Copy" in this sense means that `func1` just points to the same address as `func2` does, yes. This is how all assignment works in Python.

Comment: is it safe to say that func1 is an instance of turn_into_another_func with the argument func2.
and that func1 is "hiding" the piece of code previously called func1?
if that the case is the garbage collector remove the function func1 from the stack because nothing is "pointing" at it?

Comment: It is not correct to say that `func1` is an instance of `turn_into_another_func`. `func1` is just identical to `func2`, which you can see by doing `func1 is func2` (which will be True). It is true that the function formerly known as `func1` will be garbage collected.

Comment: `func1 = turn_into_another_func(func2)` is 100% equivalent with `func1 = func2`.

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the function `func1` on the 10th line. You have made it equivalent to `func2` in every way. You are just reassigning the variable `func1` (that holds a function) to hold the function that is held in the variable `func2`.